# How to get Json Property name in data annotation model validation results in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions, data-annotations

I am validating Data Model using Data Annotations in .NET Core C#.

**Model:**

```
public class UserDetails
{
    /// <summary>
    /// First name of user
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    [DisplayName("firstName")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**Validation Extension Class:**

```
 public static class RequestValidationExtension
  {
    public static bool IsValid(this object o, out ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults)
    {
        validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(o, new ValidationContext(o, null, null), validationResults, true);
    }
  }
```

**Checking data model validation in azure function class**

```
           UserDetails userRequest= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails>(requestBody);

            //Validate Data Annotations.
            if (!userRequest.IsValid(validationResults: out var validationResults))
            {
                string propertyName = validationResults.Select(s => s.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault().ToString();  -- o/p: FirstName not firstName
               string errorMessage = validationResults.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage);
            }
```

**Current Output:**

The string `propertyName`  returns `FirstName` not `firstName`.
I need camelCase value whatever I am providing in `JsonProperty()`

**ExpectedOutput:**

`firstName`

**My Goal:**

I have custom exception class shown below for which I have `targetField` to be set with model json property name.

```
{
    "errordetails": {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "functionName": "CreateUser",
        "errorMessage": "First name is required.",
        "targetField": "firstName"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767130/how-to-get-json-property-name-in-data-annotation-model-validation-results-in-ne

Comment: Can you please explain why do you want this? `FirstName` is expected here, because it is member name, there is no member with name `firstName` in `UserDetails`. You can do some reflection to values from attributes if needed.

Comment: @GuruStron In my custom exception message, I have ```targetField```. My goal is to display "targetField" value  in exception message as JSON Property name(which is mentioned in camelCase approach).

Comment: I don't see `targetField` mentioned anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In .net 7.0+ which I did not test for now, you only need to set the following:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });
```

For <.net7.0 which I tested, you create an inheritance of ProblemDetailsFactory:

```
public sealed class CustomProblemDetailsFactory : ProblemDetailsFactory
{
    private readonly ApiBehaviorOptions options;
    private readonly JsonOptions jsonOptions;
    public CustomProblemDetailsFactory(IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions> options, IOptions<JsonOptions> jsonOptions)
{
    this.options = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    this.jsonOptions = jsonOptions?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonOptions));
}

public override ProblemDetails CreateProblemDetails(
    HttpContext httpContext,
    int? statusCode = null,
    string title = null,
    string type = null,
    string detail = null,
    string instance = null)
{
    statusCode ??= 500;

    var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
    {
        Status = statusCode,
        Title = title,
        Type = type,
        Detail = detail,
        Instance = instance,
    };

    ApplyProblemDetailsDefaults(httpContext, problemDetails, statusCode.Value);

    return problemDetails;
}

public override ValidationProblemDetails CreateValidationProblemDetails(
    HttpContext httpContext,
    ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary,
    int? statusCode = null,
    string title = null,
    string type = null,
    string detail = null,
    string instance = null)
{
    if(modelStateDictionary == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelStateDictionary));
    }

    statusCode ??= 400;

    var errors = modelStateDictionary.ToDictionary(
        kvp => jsonOptions?.JsonSerializerOptions?.PropertyNamingPolicy?.ConvertName(kvp.Key) ?? kvp.Key,
        kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray());

    var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(errors)
    {
        Status = statusCode,
        Type = type,
        Detail = detail,
        Instance = instance,
    };

    if(title != null)
    {
        // For validation problem details, don't overwrite the default title with null.
        problemDetails.Title = title;
    }

    ApplyProblemDetailsDefaults(httpContext, problemDetails, statusCode.Value);

    return problemDetails;
}

private void ApplyProblemDetailsDefaults(HttpContext httpContext, ProblemDetails problemDetails, int statusCode)
{
    problemDetails.Status ??= statusCode;

    if(options.ClientErrorMapping.TryGetValue(statusCode, out var clientErrorData))
    {
        problemDetails.Title ??= clientErrorData.Title;
        problemDetails.Type ??= clientErrorData.Link;
    }

    var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? httpContext?.TraceIdentifier;

    if(traceId != null)
    {
        problemDetails.Extensions["traceId"] = traceId;
    }
}
}
```

After that, just register it as singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<ProblemDetailsFactory, CustomProblemDetailsFactory>();
```

And register the camel casing for the entirety of your project as mentioned above for .net 7+. Of course, if you need a different serialization output, you change the extension of ProblemDetailsFactory class. I hope this helps. Got it from this thread:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7439#issuecomment-541625844